# How can I get sql results over 100 in apache zeppelin?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

When I execute this query in apache-zeppelin I get only 100 results with 'Results are limited by 100.' message.

```
%sql
SELECT ip
FROM log
```

So I appended 'Limit 10000' in SQL query, but it returns only 100 results again.

```
%sql
SELECT ip
FROM log
LIMIT 10000
```

So, How can I get sql results over 100 in zeppelin?

Comment: In Zeppelin 0.7.2 the option zeppelin.python.maxResult in the python interpreter configuration would be the solution but is currently not evaluated. It is a known bug and not yet fixed: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-2447

Answer (score 29):

I solved it by myself.

1. Go Interpreter tab in Zeppelin Home.
2. Adujust *zeppelin.spark.maxResult* option in spark Interpreter.

Comment: %sql is interpreted by python and not spark, so I wonder if it works